# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Mpdf\Mpdf" not found in PHP 8.2

Tags: php, mpdf

I have problem.I use php 8.2.I try to use Mpdf but error when i use it.
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Mpdf\Mpdf" not found in

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
$mpdf->Output();
```

I try to use it for export to pdf.please help me.